# If I remove a cs-file from a project in VS and get latest from DevOps, does it return to the project?

Tags: devops, project

I'm having an issue with DevOps or possibly VS where I've made changes to a cs-file under a project and under pending changes that cs-file doesnt show up as changed. Instead another file in the same folder is changed (could just be that I added something and removed). In fact no changes I make to the first cs-file seem to put it under pending. I notice its the only file with no lock symbol if that helps.

Nevertheless I need to revert the changes I made, but because I didn't think ahead and closed down VS hoping it might fix the issue, I cannot now CTRL+Z back the changes I made.

So I was hoping maybe I could just remove the file from the project and get latest and whats stored in DevOps will replace it. Can anyone confirm if this would work?

Thanks for any help in advance.

/Per

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the cs-file was not included when getting latest from the project from DevOps, I got it again specifically from Team Explorer and overwrote the changes through a conflict that occurred.

Thanks anyway!